# Java HIBERNATE + Spring Security. Не получается проверить работу Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть готовый проект на Java с использованием HIBERNATE, Primefaces и бд PostgreSQL. Сказали прикрутить Spring Security к логину и регистрации. Вроде всё сделал, но не понимаю как проверить работу Spring Security. Кто может подсказать как продебажить его? Уже 3 дня пытаюсь разобраться. Документация не помогает
[image: WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter]

[image: SecurityUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService]

Answer (score 1):

**1) Авторизация в системе:**

*Вариант 1:*

Вам необходимо создать пользователя в БД, затем закодировать его пароль через какой-нибудь `BCrypto-online`(google в помощь). После чего написать метод авторизации, используя методы из `Spring Security`.

*Вариант 2:*

Вы можете написать метод регистрации, затем зарегистрироваться. После чего написать метод авторизации, используя методы из `Spring Security`, соответственно, за тем авторизоваться.

пример добавления `Spring Security`: https://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security

**2) CSRF and CORS:**

Добавьте после `csrf().disable()` следующий код: `.cors().disable()`.
Все вместе должно выглядеть так: `.cors().disable().csrf().disable()`.
Иначе у Вас будет всегда выводится `403` ошибка `HTTPS` - `FORBIDDEN`, даже если Вы авторизовались верно в системе.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое, буду думать

Answer (score 0):

https://habr.com/ru/post/482552/

Мне очень помогла эта статья, тоже долго не мог прикрутить авторизацию по ролям. Но благодаря ей, я достиг своей цели.

В данной статье говорится о регистрации и автоматически присваиваемой роли, роли админ, где он может назначать роль в своей учетной записи. В дальнейшем Вы сами можете создавать роли и прописывать им ссылки в configSpringSecurity. Также создать класс `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler` и переадресовывать на страницу в зависимости от авторизованной роли

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю